# Plotting libraries for Scala on Zeppelin

Tags: visualization, scala

My main question is it looks like [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin-project.org/) limit the display of the results to on 1000, I know that I can change this number but when I change it Zeppelin become slow. And it looks like the default plotting tool of Zeppelin also plot the first 1000 results.
Is there a configuration or a way to make the plotting tool plot all the data?

If no, is there any equivalent for Matlibplot to Scala on Zeppelin?

Comment: Charting is getting better in Zeppelin 0.7.X, but there is a product I am about to try. [https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vegas](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas) is a library that strives to substitute for matplotlib in Zeppelin/Spark environments. It works on Spark DataFrames.
The project is no longer maintain.